# Highcharts line chart with multi colored areas

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a line chart in highcharts with multi-colored areas. I have some timed data I'm trying to render that also has a status on each result. When the status is a certain color I'd like to change the color of the area beneath the line graph.

Like so:

[image]

Here's a sample of some of my data:

```
{"GmtDateTime": "2013-07-31 12:20:15", "Speed": 40.068, "StatusCode": "1"}, 
{"GmtDateTime": "2013-07-31 12:30:11", "Speed": 41.823, "StatusCode": "2"}, 
{"GmtDateTime": "2013-07-31 12:40:15", "Speed": 41.987, "StatusCode": "1"}, 
{"GmtDateTime": "2013-07-31 12:50:11", "Speed": 40.192, "StatusCode": "3"}, 
{"GmtDateTime": "2013-07-31 13:00:12", "Speed": 40.877, "StatusCode": "3"}, 
{"GmtDateTime": "2013-07-31 13:10:12", "Speed": 40.364, "StatusCode": "2"}, 
{"GmtDateTime": "2013-07-31 13:20:15", "Speed": 44.331, "StatusCode": "1"}, 
{"GmtDateTime": "2013-07-31 13:30:14", "Speed": 42.89, "StatusCode": "1"},
```

The x-axis is "GMTDatetime", the y-axis is "Speed", and the range color is "StatusCode".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pleas provide more information / code like your area div name...

Comment: What other information? There is no code to show. That image was just made in Paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts use timestamps (time in miliseconds) not dates as you have. In series / data objects should have x/y parameter, not i.e "Speed". As a results your json should looks like:

```
{y: Date.UTC(2012,12,2), y: 42.89, "StatusCode": "1"}
```

Date.UTC allows ot return time in miliseconds.

In case when you need to have different color of part chart, you need to use additional serie.

EDIT:

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/D4sbc/

Comment: Yeah I'm parsing the data into that format. It's not the data I need help with it's the styling of the chart.